# How to convert a string of 10 double-values into 10 separated doubles in c++

Tags: c++, string, double

i have a question i didn´t find an answer to.. i don´t know if i missed something, but here i go:

I´m trying to convert a string that i read in from a file into 10 splitted doubles.

This is how i read in the last row in my file which contains values like this:

{1444.555;1553.9999; ....and so on}

What i´m trying to do is an Array out of this string which consists of these values like

```
    Array[0]=1444.555
    Array[1]=1553.999
```

and so on..

My code-snippet till here looks like this:

```
    string line;
    string new1;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        new1 = line;

    }
    cout << new1 << endl;
    myfile.close();
```

So i need a conversion of the **new1**-string to an Array of doubles.

Alternatively you could tell me how to parse the content of a string like this one to a Matrix[i][j]? Actually this is what i´m trying to do.

Comment: Try out ``scanf("{%d; %d; %d}", value1, value2, value3); `` for arrays with 3 elements. -- You also mixed decimal points and commas, which should be points, to be compatible on all systems! -- For different-sized arrays you should split them by the semicolon and ignore the first and last characters (the braces).

Comment: This reads like homework assignment to parse the input.  What work on this have you done?  Where exactly are you stuck?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You should directly read the double's from std::cin. I would create a `struct` to represent your data set(s) and define operator>> for it, which enforces the correct format and reads the data. I generally wouldn't use scanf in C++.

Comment: i did some research.. and i just found **stringstream**-solutions i tried out that didn´t work..

@smoothware could you give a short example maybe?

Comment: @MattisSeehaus perhaps something like this (only briefly tested)? https://pastebin.com/sPffyyim  P.S.: Reading a string, then creating a stringstream from said string, then reading the doubles from the stringstream is just as bad. Just read the doubles directly from the source input stream, without reading them into a string first

Comment: @smoothware i answered this question. was this the way you proposed, too?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers but i found a way to do it.

I used vectors now and changed the separator between the doubles to whitespaces. So my code looks like this now:

```
 #include <vectors>
....
....
ifstream myfile("example.txt", std::ios::in);
    vector<double> scores;


    //check 
    if (!myfile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "There was a problem opening the input file!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    //store values
    double num = 0.0;

    while (myfile >> num) {
        scores.push_back(num);
    }

    // extract last line in my file to my Matrix
    for (i = 0; i <= x_max; i++) {

        Matrix[i][0] = scores[i + m_max * (y_max-1)];

        cout << Matrix[i][0] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: If your file is actually in the format you showed, this won't read a single number, as it will fail at the first '{'. Unless you have just a bunch of whitespace separated values, in which case your question was very misleading.

Comment: ah shit.. i forgot to mention that i changed the separator to whitespaces.. good that you remind me. i´ll add that to the "answer"..